# Printing Powershell output into Csv

Tags: powershell, scripting, powershell-2.0

How to print powershell output into a csv file? My task is to connect Powershell to azure ad then get users with duplicate licenses and then print the user and all groups user is present in. The initial code I have prepared where I get user and the groups he is present in, but I dont know how to export this into a csv file. Also the number of groups a user is present in varies so using the method where we specify column1=, colum2= ... might not work. I want to show the result in csv with username and groups seperated by commas. Want to know how to do that.

Answer (score 0):

You are probably looking for the [Export-Csv](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/export-csv?view=powershell-7.2&WT.mc_id=AZ-MVP-5003203) cmdlet.

Here an example:

```
Get-Process | Export-Csv -Path .\Processes.csv -Delimiter ',' -NoTypeInformation
```